# Htaccess redirect some specifics URL to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I try to redirect all old mobile URLs of my website to homepage.
So redirect www.website.com/Mobile/xxxxx to www.website.com/ and all similar URLs. And the /Mobile/ without anything after also.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I tried RewriteRule ^Mobile/.*$ / [L] but not working

Comment: Try `RedirectMatch 301 ^Mobile(.*)?$ /`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how many URLs you need to redirect, but you would do this using `Redirect 301`.

So for example:

```
Redirect 301 /mobile.html https://www.website.com/
Redirect 301 /mobile/example.html https://www.website.com/
...
Redirect 301 /mobile/example2.html https://www.website.com/
```

and so on.

`301` is a permanent redirection, so make sure you direct the correct URLs. While testing I advise you use `302` as this will be temporary, then switch it back to `301` once you're happy.

Comment: thank you for your answer, there are a lot of URLs so i search for something which redirect all url start by /mobile/ with anything after. And for the redirection part is it possible to not specify the complete URL https://www.website.com/ ?